# Large files and multiple if statement Issues in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am having speed issues using multiple "if/elif statements" when trying to read through and print a large file. When timing my code it took almost 10 mins to read through and replace 2MB file lol. The sample file I used had roughly 8 characters on a line. Example (ABAABAA, AAAAA, BAABABAB)

```
with open("text2.txt","r") as File1:
        for line in File1:
                    W = 'A'
                    Z = 'B'
                    counting1 = line.count(W)
                    counting2 = line.count(Z)
                    if counting1 == 1:
                        removeW = line.replace(W,'C')
                        removeZ = line.replace(Z,'D')
                        print (removeW)
                        print (removeZ)
                        if counting2 == 2:
                            removeW = line.replace(W,'E')
                            removeZ = line.replace(Z,'F')
                            print (removeW)
                            print (removeZ)
                    elif counting1 == 2:
                        removeW = line.replace(W,'G')
                        removeZ = line.replace(Z,'H')
                        if counting2 == 3:
                            removeW = line.replace(W,'E')
                            removeZ = line.replace(Z,'F')
                            print (removeW)
                            print (removeZ)
                    elif counting1 == 3:
                        removeW = line.replace(W,'I')
                        removeZ = line.replace(Z,'J')
                        print (removeW)
                        print (removeZ)
```

I have a decent computer, because I'm so new at coding can someone assist me with cleaning that up and/or teach me just a better process for speed purposes. I have 2 nested if statements and because of the different possibilities not sure a better way.

Comment: Is that your entire program? And are you printing the file to screen or redirecting output to another file?

Comment: I eventually will be writing it to another text file but for the sake of learning, I  was just printing it. and yes that is the entire program idea. replacing characters from a line of large files based upon 8 characters at a time.

Comment: Printing a two meg file of 8 char lines can take a while so that's probably what's eating up the bulk of your time. There are better ways to write this code but I don't think what you have so far is killing performance. Redirect the output of your script to something other than your screen and time it. It should take a lot less time.

Comment: God... was pretty much instance writing to just a file. Just for a great learning lesson and so I can give you the well earned answer for my questions what would be a better way to do something like that?

Comment: Not really a good fit for the site, I think, it's a little too vague and 'code-reviewy' (for which there is a separate site!). It's also not clear what the exact problem you're solving is.

Comment: well I still appreciate the answer. kinda strange that printing to screen would add 10 mins verses almost instant. kinda cool to understand that aspect, Thanks.